# sleep and usleep start wrong

Tags: c++, sleep, usleep

In C++ I use `usleep` in my "main" path and call the function `out` before.

```
out();
usleep(4000000);
```

`out` just prints something on the screen. Unfortunately the print appears on the screen only after 4 seconds, though the `out()` function call is before the `usleep` command. I work on a raspberry with raspbian. How can it be that not first the function `out()`; is called and then `usleep` starts but the other way round?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what `out()` does.

Comment: You probably need to flush your output buffer in `out()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ in order to decrease the time of IO we have buffered output. What that means, is that calls that write to screen/disk do not always write to the real device.

Let's take for example this code:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10000; x++)
    std::cout << "a";
```

If "a" would be written to the screen each time, it would take a long time. Instead, the whole buffer is written every n characters.

In order to write the non full buffer to the screen you have several options:

Use std::flush like this:

```
std::cout << std::flush;
```

Std::endl also uses flush:

```
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: great, that works, thanks a lot :-) I have the same problem with the command outfile.write(buffer,10); Is there something like flush for this also?

Comment: Found out it works the same way with flush, thanks a lot I was trying this alone for hours... :-)!! This it how it works: Instead of outfile.write(buffer,10) I use: string buffer="test"; outfile << buffer << flush;